# How to map foreign key relations in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have customer class   and Address class  as below:
officeAddressId,homeAddressId, and secondaryAddressId in Customer class are for foreign key mapping in tables.

```
  public class customer implements serializable
    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID= -5830229553758180137L;
    int age;
    String officeAddressId= null;
    String homeAddressId= null;
    String secondaryAddressId= null;
    }

public class Address implements serializable
{
        private static final long serialVersionUID= -5130229553758180137L;
        private String              addressId           = null;
    private String              addressLine         = null;
    private String              cityName            = null;
    private String              stateName           = null;
    private String              countryName         = null;
    private String              pincode             = null;
}
```

My database table is straight forward:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
customerID varchar(40) primary key,
officeAddressId varchar(40),
homeAddressId varchar(40),
secondaryAddressId varchar(40),
age int 
);

CREATE TABLE Address
(
addressID varchar(40) primary key,
addressLine varchar(40),
cityName varchar(40),
stateName varchar(40),
countryName varchar(40),
pincode varchar(10),
);
```

I make address objects (3 objects for address one for home,office and secondarycontact)  and customer object at service layer and open transaction. I am not sure how should I give the foreign key relation in hbm mapping files and how do I save these four objects(3 address objects and 1 customer object) and in which order that the foreign key relations are persisted in database correctly.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This is a `many-to-one` relationship between `Customer` (should be capitalized) and `Address`. In `Customer` class, change `String officeAddressId` to `Address officeAddress`.

Comment: I don't now how much data you will put in your database, but you have some redundancy in your table. Because for every address you save the city **and** the corresponding state, pin code and country name. You could create another table with pin code and country name as key. Or if it is no world wide application, your creating -  just the pin code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer better tailored to your question.

Assuming your *AddressId columns in the `customer` table can be foreign keys, then you should map the relationship as a `many-to-one` in your `Customer` Hibernate mapping/class. (Note that Java classes should begin with capital letter.)

In `Customer` class:

```
//each of these with getters/setters
Address officeAddress;
Address homeAddress;
Address secondaryAddress;
```

In `Customer.hbm.xml` file:

```
<many-to-one name="officeAddress" class="[package.name.]Address" column="officeAddressId"/>
<many-to-one name="homeAddress" class="[package.name.]Address" column="homeAddressId"/>
<many-to-one name="secondaryAddress" class="[package.name.]Address" column="secondaryAddressId"/>
```

Then, the explicit way to create/save these objects (perhaps in a DAO method) is to get access to a Hibernate `Session` (via `SessionFactory`), create/save the `Address` objects, set those on the `Customer` object, and then save it. Something like this:

```
//in DAO create logic
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); //or openSession()
Address office = new Address();
Address home = new Address();
Address secondary = new Address();
//populate Address objects...
session.saveOrUpdate(office);
session.saveOrUpdate(home);
session.saveOrUpdate(secondary);
Customer customer = new Customer();
//populate Customer object...
customer.setOfficeAddress(office);
customer.setHomeAddress(home);
customer.setSecondaryAddress(secondary);
session.saveOrUpdate(customer);
```

If you need to update which `Address` entities a `Customer` references, then `get` the objects, set the correct `Address` objects again, and save the `Customer`:

```
//in DAO update logic
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); //or openSession()
Customer customer = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, customerId);
Address address = (Address) session.get(Address.class, addressId);
customer.setOfficeAddress(address);
session.saveOrUpdate(customer); //updates officeAddressId column to value of addressId
```

Pretty verbose, but explicit and straightforward.

Comment: First of all, thanks for detailed help. One ques--> does that mean I always have to resort to composition of objects in case of using Hibernate?

Comment: You don't have to. You could still map a FK column as a String or primitive `property` (as opposed to `many-to-one`), but doing so will not allow you to leverage Hibernate for automatic relationship lookups or validation. You would have to do your own `Address` retrievals every time you fetched a `Customer` entity. But if you compose a `Customer` with `Address`es, Hibernate will fetch them for you. So it just depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

First, change name of your customer class to Customer. Then:

```
public Class Customer implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "office_address_id")
    private Address officeAddress;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "home_address_id")
    private Address homeAddress;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "secondary_address_id")
    private Address secondaryAddress;

    ...
}
```

and

```
public Class Address implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "officeAddress")
    private Set<Customer> officeCustomers = new HashSet<Customer>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "homeAddress")
    private Set<Customer> homeCustomers = new HashSet<Customer>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "secondaryAddress")
    private Set<Customer> secondaryCustomers = new HashSet<Customer>(0);

    ...
}
```

and of course you can create getter for all customers in Address class.

Comment: Is composition must with hibernate? Cann't we use just Id field?